# Linux: Compile using a specific ncurses version when both V6 and V5 are installed?

Tags: linux, gcc, ncurses

In Linux, how can I choose which ncurses library to build against when both V5 and V6 are installed?

Right now it defaults to V6 (the project is the same as when it was building to V5 before the upgrade from Debian Jessie to Buster).

TIA!!

Comment: That's done using appropriate (platform/configuration-specific) compiler- and linker-options.

Comment: How did you install the libraries?  They probably each come with a `.pc` file that says the compiler options to use, and you can just look at that file or you can get the data from it using `pkg-config`.

Comment: I am just using debian buster.  what are the appropriate options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian has several packages for [ncurses](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?dist=oldstable;package=ncurses) (I find the bug-reporting links easier to navigate than the [package-tracking](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ncurses)).  At the moment, buster is ["oldstable"](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBuster).  That has development packages for ABI 5 and 6:

- libncurses-dev
- libncursesw-dev
- libncurses5-dev
- libncursesw5-dev

Each of those has a package-page which includes a list of files for each architecture, e.g., [this](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libncurses-dev), and for example

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/form.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/formw.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/menu.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/menuw.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ncurses++.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ncurses++w.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ncurses.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ncursesw.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/panel.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/panelw.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/tic.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/tinfo.pc
```

Generally, the filename for the ".pc" files is useful as a parameter to `pkg-config`, e.g.,

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs libncurses-dev
```

which prints the **`-I`**, **`-D`**, **`-L`** and **-l** options you'd use in a makefile or script.

You don't have to search through the webpages for that;

```
dpkg -l | grep 'ncurses'
```

lists the package with "ncurses" in their name, and for the example shown

```
dpkg -L libncurses-dev | grep -F .pc
```

shows the pkg-config files.

In a command-line, I could do this:

```
gcc -c $(pkg-config --cflags libncurses-dev) foo.c
```

for just the compiler, or to compile/link:

```
gcc -o foo $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libncurses-dev) foo.c
```

The package also has the "*-config" scripts which give similar information, without using `pkg-config`, e.g.,

```
/usr/bin/ncurses5-config
/usr/bin/ncurses6-config
/usr/bin/ncursesw5-config
/usr/bin/ncursesw6-config
```

In the Debian development packages, it appears that there are ".pc" files only for ABI 6.  But the "-config" files are provided for both ABI 5 and 6.  So you should be able to compile with ABI 5, e.g,.

```
gcc -c $(ncurses5-config --cflags libncurses-dev) foo.c
```